# LDAP health check failed after running spring-batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I run a spring-batch project to fetch some data from an external API. It runs successfully but raises the following NPE raised after execution:

```
2019-07-08 10:26:53.040 |;| 8503 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
2019-07-08 10:26:53.633 |;| 8503 --- [on(6)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.actuate.ldap.LdapHealthIndicator   : LDAP health check failed

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:459)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.SimpleDirContextAuthenticationStrategy.setupEnvironment(SimpleDirContextAuthenticationStrategy.java:42)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.setupAuthenticatedEnvironment(AbstractContextSource.java:194)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getAuthenticatedEnv(AbstractContextSource.java:582)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.doGetContext(AbstractContextSource.java:134)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getReadOnlyContext(AbstractContextSource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeReadOnly(LdapTemplate.java:802)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.ldap.LdapHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(LdapHealthIndicator.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:96)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The error seems to come from null values (bothe for `userDn` and `password`) in the following method:

```
# org.springframework.ldap.core.support.SimpleDirContextAuthenticationStrategy

public void setupEnvironment(Hashtable<String, Object> env, String userDn, String password) {
  env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, SIMPLE_AUTHENTICATION);
  env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userDn);
  env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
}
```

What is the problem with that?

Used with:

- Oracle jdk 8
- `spring-boot-starter-parent`: 2.1.6
- `spring-batch-core`: 4.1.2
- `spring-core`: 5.1.8

Comment: I see `Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]` which means the error happens after the spring batch job has finished and is not related to spring batch (unless your job puts `null` values in the ldap env).

Comment: Yeah, it seems like there was a [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/pull/474) in spring-ldap project. I fixed by setting `management.health.ldap.enabled` to `false` in my `application.yml` file.